# Explicit form for a difficult sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let us define infinite sequence $x_n$ as such: the first term of the sequence is $x_1=1$. Then, the next $x_1$ terms are 2. The next term is 1. The next $x_2$ terms are 2. The next term is 1. The next $x_3$ terms are 2. The next term is 1. And so and so forth...

Can anyone provide explicit formula for the $n$th term of this sequence? Or please provide any insight on any patterns that may exist.

For reference, here is how the sequence goes for the first several terms:

1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1

Comment: +1 : interesting query.

Comment: How is  $x_2$ defined?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri since $x_1=1$, the next term (namely $x_2$) is defined to be $2$.

Comment: $x_2=2$, as defined by the problem statement (because $x_1=1$ and the next $x_1$ terms are 2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [$A001468$](https://oeis.org/A001468) in the OEIS.
The formula is:

$$a_n = \lfloor(n+1)\varphi\rfloor - \lfloor n\varphi\rfloor,$$

where $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ is the golden ratio.